# TYPO3 Insert records element: detect number of items

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x

Is there any way to detect in fluid or typoscript (or anything else) if an "Insert Records" CE from `fluid_styled_content` contains **one or multiple items**?

The use case:

I use "insert records" to display contacts from a custom extbase extension on a page, and I'd like to get a different title and layout if there are one or several items.

Comment: does this answer something ? `<f:if condition="{f:count(subject: records.inserted)} > 1">` as a condition in your template

Comment: before I try this: do you mean it literally? the problem is that I don't get an array of all records, but each record is parsed individually to the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert Records is rendered using the `RECORDS` content object. In `\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\RecordsContentObject::render()` I see no option to read the number of items or the current item number that is rendered from the contentObjectRenderer object that renders a single item.

Comment: Thanks! I feared that already. Do you think it would be worth a feature request? Why not, actually...

Comment: If someone hurries a bit it can go as a feature in version 8. For 7.x it won't be possible to ad features anymore.